# containerized Openstack services

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openstack-glance, openstack-keystone

I have a difficulties in the following question:
"Does it make sense to containerized/dockerize the openstack controlling services like Neurtron/Cinder/Glance/Keystone server services (neutron-API ,etc) and nova controlling services like Nova-api (other than the nova-compute)?
I have research about the Openstack Kolla project, but it couldn't help me to absorb the idea behind it.

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenStack Foundation wrote a [white paper](https://www.openstack.org/use-cases/containers/leveraging-containers-and-openstack/) covering OpenStack and containers. It includes a paragraph about the benefits of containerizing OpenStack services.